# Бот не удаляет данные из база данных

Tags: python, termux

Когда в боте нажимаем кнопку, бот должен удалить данные из базы данных, но они не удаляются.

Структуры таблицы

```sql
CREATE TABLE "queue" (
    "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "chat_id" REAL NOT NULL
)
```

Код из bot.py

```py
elif message.text == 'Манъ кардани ҷустуҷӯ':
    db.delete_queue(message.chat.id)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ҷустуҷу манъ карда шуд, /menu')
```

Код из basadate.py

```py
def delete_queue(self, chat_id):
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute("DELETE FROM `queue` WHERE  `chat_id` = ?", (chat_id,))
```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, структуру таблицы из которой удаляете (через кнопку [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1512872/edit)) Как минимум нужен id записи для удаления.

Comment: наверняка, это `sqlite`, вам нужно сделать `commit` после удаления

Comment: @DaniilLoban добавил посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: DELETE FROM "queue" WHERE  "chat_id" = ? - queue и chat_id у вас текст, сделайте так DELETE FROM queue WHERE  chat_id = ?  БЕЗ АПОСТРОФОВ

Comment: Cудя по запросу все должно работать, какие-то ошибки появляются? Если да то, пожалуйста, добавьте к вопросу.

Comment: @DaniilLoban во время запускания бота нету ошибок но как там сказал кнопка не работает или из база данных не удаляет

Comment: попробуйте проверить идет ли вызов `delete_queue`, можете например `print` написать там в первой строке —  что-то вывести в консоль, у меня есть мнение, что дело не запросе, а в чем-то ином, но по этим строкам кода ничего не сказать, а запрос рабочий.

Comment: Почему `REAL`? Это подразумевает преобразование целого числа в число с плавающей точкой, что на больших chat_id приведёт к потере точности и непредсказуемым результатам

Comment: @andreymal что надо выбирать?

Comment: Вероятно `INTEGER` — в него влезают значения до 9223372036854775807 включительно (надеюсь, что chat_id больше не бывает)